# Collection of $\{xU\}$ are neighbourhoods of $x$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology

This exercise is in the context of Lie Groups.

> Exercise: Show that the collection $\{xU\}$, over all neighborhoods of $U$ of $e$, is a base of neighborhoods for $x$(similarly for $\{Ux\}$)

I thought of solving this question in the folloing way:

Consider:

$L:G\times U\to G$

such that $L(x,u)=xu$ such that $u\in U$

Fixing $x$, L is a diffeomorphism and $L(x,e)=x$  once $e\in U$, so $x\in Ux$, as well as the other points, forming a neighborhood.

**Question**

How do I prove the other points $L(x,u)$ will be in $\{xU\}$? It seems that is the definiton of $xU$.

Comment: By definition $xU = \{xu \; : \; u \in U\}$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AlexG. I know that definition. I want to know how to prove the assertion.

Comment: "How do I prove the other points $L(x, u)$ will be in $xU$?" Answer: $L(x, u) = xu \in  xU$ by definition of $xU$.

Comment: Not trying to be snarky. I am having trouble discerning what you're asking exactly.

Comment: You're overusing letters and it's confusing you. What is the definition of a *base of neighborhoods at $p$*? If all neighborhoods $U$ of $e$ satisfy it at $e$, why do not all the neighborhoods $xU$ of $x$ satisfy it at $x$? Are you trying to understand why $xU$ is an open set if $U$ is open?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I am trying to understand if why xU is open. I think that boils down to prove $L:G\times G\to G $ is open, but I am not seeing exactly how to prove for an arbitrary product operation.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your help. I understood it. $L_g$ is an open mapping because $L_{g^-1}$ is its inverse and by Lie Group definition it is $C^\infty$.

Comment: There you go. :) I suggest you write an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $L: G\times G\to G$ as the left translation, then $L$ is a diffeomorphism. L is obviously invective and subjective. But is it open? Does it have a continuously differentiable inverse? Bu Lie Group definition the operations $L_g(x)=gx$ and $L_{g^{-1}}(x)=g^-1 x$ are $C^{\infty}$. Noting that $L_{g^{-1}}\circ L_g(x)=g^{-1}gx=x$. The function has a $C^{\infty}$ inverse, hence it is open. Then $L_x(U)$ is an open set containing $x$ once $L_x(e)=x$, so xU is a neighbourhood of x. The same holds for every open set hence $\{xU\}$ constitutes the collection of all neighbourhoods.
In a similar way, this applies to the right translation.